# Is the set of all sums-of-rationals-that-give-one countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity

Some (but not all) sums of rational numbers gives us 1 as a result. For instance:

$$\frac12 + \frac12 = 1$$
$$\frac13 + \frac23 = 1$$
$$\frac37 + \frac{3}{14} + \frac{5}{14}  = 1$$

Is the set of all of these sums countable?

Sums that differ just by their addends ordering are the same. So $(\frac25+\frac35)$ is the same element as $(\frac35+\frac25$), and shouldn't be counted twice.

Also, for avoiding duplicity, all fractions should be in their irreducible form. No no need to count $(\frac26 + \frac23)$ if we already have $(\frac13 + \frac23)$.

If the set is countable, **what would be a mapping function from $\mathbb N$ to this set?**

Answer (score 10):

Since the set of rationals is countable, the set of all finite sets of rationals is countable, and therefore the set of all finite sums of rationals is countable. In particular, the set of finite sets of rationals with sum $1$ is countable. An explicit bijection between this set and $\Bbb N$ would be messy.

**Added:** If you limit yourself to finite sums of positive rationals, you can order the sums as follows. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $\mathscr{F}_n$ be the set of all [multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) $F$ of positive rationals such that $\sum F=1$, $|F|\le n$, and whenever $\frac{p}q\in F$ is in lowest terms, then $q\le n$. For example, the only member of $\mathscr{F}_1$ is $\{\!\{1\}\!\}$, and the only members of $\mathscr{F}_2$ are $\{\!\{1\}\!\}$ and $\left\{\!\!\left\{\frac12,\frac12\right\}\!\!\right\}$, and

$$\mathscr{F}_3=\left\{\{\!\{1\}\!\},\left\{\!\!\left\{\frac12,\frac12\right\}\!\!\right\},\left\{\!\!\left\{\frac13,\frac13,\frac13\right\}\!\!\right\},\left\{\!\!\left\{\frac23,\frac13\right\}\!\!\right\}\right\}\;.$$

If $F=\{\!\{r_1,\ldots,r_\ell\}\!\},G=\{\!\{s_1,\ldots,s_m\}\!\}\in\mathscr{F}_n$, where $r_1\ge\ldots\ge r_\ell$ and $s_1\ge\ldots\ge s_m$, define $F\prec_n G$ iff either $\ell<m$, or $\ell=m$ and $r_k>s_k$, where $k=\min\{i:r_i\ne s_i\}$; $\prec_n$ is a strict linear order on $\mathscr{F}_n$.

Let $\mathscr{F}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\mathscr{F}_n$, and for each $F\in\mathscr{F}$ let $n(F)=\min\{k\in\Bbb Z^+:F\in\mathscr{F}_k\}$. For $F,G\in\mathscr{F}$ define $F\prec G$ iff either $n(F)<n(G)$, or $n(F)=n(G)$ and $F\prec_{n(F)} G$; then $\langle\mathscr{F},\prec\rangle$ is a strict linear order that is order-isomorphic to $\langle\Bbb N,<\rangle$. I’d not care to try to write down the order isomorphism explicitly, but this does at least give the explicit ordering of $\mathscr{F}$ corresponding to such a bijection.

Comment: If infinite sums were allowed, would it then necessarily be uncountable?

Comment: @Leidem: It would be provably uncountable; I don’t know exactly what you mean here by *necessarily*.

Comment: Your point makes perfect sense, Brian. But I'm really interested in seeing this mapping/bijection, as I have tried to no avail to find an ordering that would cover all those sums.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks. I meant nothing special about the word necessarily.

Comment: @bruno: I’ve added an explicit ordering of the sums from which a bijection with $\Bbb N$ could in principle be derived, though the bijection itself is still messier than I care to deal with.

Comment: @PyRulez: That gives you a linear order, but not one that’s order-isomorphic to $\Bbb N$: there are infinitely many two-element sets, infinitely many three-element sets, and so on.